# Which God is known as God of Silence?

Tags: gods, goddess

Which God or Goddess is known as God of Silence in Hindu Religion?

Comment: Dakshinamurthy, an incarnation of Shiva, teaches in silence.

Answer (score 3):

Dakshinamurthy, an aspect of Shiva and deity of wisdom, can be regarded as the god of silence since he parts knowledge by observing silence:

> **मौनव्याख्या** प्रकटित परब्रह्मतत्त्वं युवानं
>   वर्षिष्ठांते वसद् ऋषिगणैः आवृतं ब्रह्मनिष्ठैः ।
>   आचार्येन्द्रं करकलित चिन्मुद्रमानंदमूर्तिं
>   स्वात्मारामं मुदितवदनं दक्षिणामूर्तिमीडे ॥१॥
>
> **English Translation**: Whose exposition through **profound silence** awakens the Knowledge of the Supreme Brahman in the hearts of His disciples; Who is Himself youthful but sits surrounded by old and great sages who are devoted to Brahman, the hands of the Supreme spiritual teacher is forming the Cin-Mudra (gesture of the Knowledge of Brahman) and Whose appearance is still and blissful, Who rejoices in His own Self which is reflected on His blissful face; Salutations to that Sri Dakshinamurthy. (**Adi-Shankaracharya's Dakshinamurthy Stotram, Verse 1**)

Comment: No, He is mauna does not mean He is the God of silence

Comment: No mauna here is not silence. There's hidden wisdom behind it!

Answer (score 1):

Silence is the english word for Mauna (मौन).  The word Mauna comes from Muni, reference : [मौन - Sanskrit Dictionary](https://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%A8&lang=sans&action=Search)

According to the Viveka-Chudamoni, silence is the first gate to yoga:

> yogasya prathamam dvaaram **baang-nirodho** (370). baang-nirodha means silence.

Srimad-Bhagavatam says

> **yogaanntaraayan** **mounena**(7/15) :The yogi should win over his obstacles to yoga by adopting silence.

According to Linga-Purana also, mauna is a means of tapas or austerity

> brahmacharyam tathaa **maunam** niraaharakatvam eva cha/ahimsaa sarvatah shantis tapa iti avidhiyate//

And the God of the Munis or Yogis and therefore of Silence is the Paramatma,Who is described as Shiva or Vishnu. In Svaatmaprakaashika we get

> yat padam vimalam advayam shivam tat sad aham iti mounam ashraye --**I take resort to silence to reach that Ever-unstinting Non-Dual Ever-existent Supreme Abode Shiva**.

On the other hand, the famous dhyana-mantra of Sri Vishnu starting with 'saantaakaaram' also mentions Him as 'yogivir dhyana-gamyam' ie Whom the yogis attain by meditation.

**So the God of Silence is the Paramatmaa**, named as Shiva or Vishnu (or Surya or Durga/Kali or Ganesha etc).

Reference: Omkarnath Rachanavali, Mahamilan Math, Vol.1, page 375-379.